# Akka-Http: Logging up the stack or logging down the stack?

Tags: akka, akka-http

I am writing a custom directive to use cats.XorT to wrap my futures in Future[Xor[A,B]]. I have written the following code:

```
 def authenticateOrRejectWithChallenge[T](authenticator: Option[HttpCredentials] ⇒ XorTFuture[T]): AuthenticationDirective[T] =
    extractExecutionContext.flatMap { implicit ec ⇒
      extractCredentials.flatMap { cred ⇒
        onSuccess(authenticator(cred).value) flatMap {
          case Xor.Right(x) => provide(x)
          case Xor.Left(y:MyException) => reject(MyRejection(y)):Directive1[T]
          case Xor.Left(e) =>
            Directives.extractRequestContext.flatMap {
              r =>
                logger.error(e)(s"Unexpected authentication error when processing ${r.request}")
                reject(MyRejection(MyException.fromUnexpectedThrowable(e))):Directive1[T]
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

The following questions come to my mind:

- Is it stupid to log in that position and should I rather log in the rejection handler?
- How would I capture in the rejection handler the current request logger? (Directive.extractLog?)